# Accessing Pytest Pass/Fail count (Test stats) from with in code

Tags: python-2.7, pytest

Is there a way to capture the test stats (pass/fail/xfail/skipped) count when invoking pytest from with in python code using

```
exit_code = pytest.main()
```

Once the pytest is done executing the tests, I would like to collect these stats for further processing. All I could think right now is to write plugin and access "**terminalreporter**" plugins stats, but if there's a better and easy way to do this , I would love to know.

Answer (score 0):

not really a good solution (imho) but it seems to be working
have counters for run/passed/failed and increment using `pytest_runtest_logreport(self,report)` hook

```
if report.when == "setup":
    test_run += 1
if report.passed and report.when == "teardown":
    test_passed += 1
if not report.passed and report.outcome != 'skipped':
    test_failed += 1
```